# Simple Function C++

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{

return 0;
}
double C2F()
{
    f = value * 9 / 5 + 32;
    return f;
}

double K2F()
{
    f = (value - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32.0;
    return f;
}

double N2F()
{
    f = value * 60 / 11 + 32;
    return f;
}
```

Im having trouble calling these functions to calculate the temperature conversion instead of calculation it from within the cases. The program will not even compile after adding these functions. "Error: Expected a ";""

Comment: You might try not declaring them locally in `main()`. Nested functions aren't supported in C++ or C. And you'll have to add `value` to the parameter lists when you move them out.

Comment: double C2F(double = value)
{
 f = value * 9 / 5 + 32;
 return f;
}

Comment: In your functions you are not declaring f before using it. Should be "double f =  value * 9 / 5 + 32;" for example. And you need to declare the functions before defining main.

Comment: You cannot just make up stuff and expect it to work. You need to follow the rules of the C++ language. (Also, you need to update your title to be useful to the community. Right now, the title is too vague to be useful to anybody.)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot declare or define functions inside another function. Move your definitions outside of `int main(){ ... }`.

Comment: Actually, you can declare functions inside other functions, you just can't *define* them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cant declare another function in the ***main()*** function.

secondly all of your function have a return type, but surprisingly you are calling them as they are void. Make the function void instead of a return type. As for example....

```
void C2F()
{
    f = value * 9 / 5 + 32;
}
```

and then

```
case 'C':
        C2F();
        cout << value << "C is " << f << " in Farenheit" << endl;
        break;
```

OR.
You can receive the return value in a double type variable and and print the value.

```
case 'C':
    cout << value << "C is " << C2F() << " in Farenheit" << endl;
    break;
```

Comment: The functions are suppose to return a double value which holds the value converted to Fahrenheit

Comment: Then you should receive the return value in some variable. :D

Comment: You have two choice. Declare the *int main()* function at the bottom of all other function. Or declare the function prototype first. You may check how to declare a func prototype here-> http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/functions/function-declaration.html

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want.

1. Declare functions outside the main method.
2. Declare functions before the main method or use forward declarations
3. Pass the 'value' to each function as a argument.
4. Remove unnecessary variable declaration.
5. Use some validation for user inputs.
6. Use meaningful variable names.

## include

```
using namespace std;


double C2F(double f)
{       
    return f * 9 / 5 + 32;    
}

double K2F(double f)
{   
    return ((f - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32.0);   
}

double N2F(double f)
{           
    return (f * 60 / 11 + 32);

}

int main()
{
    char function;
    double value;
    cout << "This temperature Conversion program converts other temperatures to farenheit" << endl;
    cout << "The temperature types are" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "C - Celcius" << endl;
    cout << "K - Kelvin" << endl;
    cout << "N - Newton" << endl;
    cout << "X - eXit" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "To use the converter you must input a value and one of the temperature types." <<         endl;
    cout << "For example 32 C converts 32 degrees from Celsius to Fahrenheit" << endl;
    cin >> value >> function;

    function = toupper(function);

    while (function != 'X')
    {
        switch (function)
        {
        case 'C':       
            cout << value << "C is " << C2F(value) << " in Farenheit" << endl;
            break;
        case 'K':       
            cout << value << "K is " << K2F(value) << " in Farenheit" << endl;
            break;
        case 'N':
            cout << value << "N is " << N2F(value) << " in Farenheit" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Correct choices are C, K, N, X" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Please enter a value and it's type to be converted" << endl;
        cin >> value >> function;
        function = toupper(function);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to request the input 'value' from the user from within the function?

Comment: of course. I recommend you to go trough this tutorial for some basic understanding about C++ http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/